# (Proof Verification) Prove $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach Space

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, banach-spaces

> Let $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuous functions that vanish at infinity: $$C_0(\mathbb{R}) = \{ f \in C(\mathbb{R}):  \lim_{t \to \pm \infty} f(t) = 0 \}$$ Prove that $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is a closed subspace of $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ with respect to the uniform norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_u$ and therefore $(C_0(\mathbb{R}), \lVert \cdot \rVert_u)$ is a Banach space.

To prove $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is closed, consider a sequence $f_n \in C_0$ converging uniformly to $f$ in $C_b$. Then $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \lVert f-f_n \rVert_u   = \lim_{ n\to \infty} \big(sup |f(x) - f_n(x)| \big) = 0$ But $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ so $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ therefore $C_0$ is closed.

Furthermore, it is trivial to show that the $0$ function is in $C_0$. Moreover, let $f,g \in C_0$. Then $f + g \in C_0$ since the sum of two continuous functions is continuous, and $ \lim_{t \to \pm \infty} f(t) + g(t) = \lim_{t \to \pm \infty} f(t) + \lim_{t \to \pm \infty} g(t) = 0 + 0 = 0 $

Lastly, take $f \in C_0$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $cf$ is continuous since its a scalar multiple of a continuous function. Also, $\lim_{t \to \pm \infty} c f(t) = c \lim_{t \to \pm \infty} = c*0 = 0$

This proves $C_0$ is a subspace, and since $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space $C_0$ is also a Banach space.

Is my proof correct? Anything I could improve on?

Also if someone could please edit to fix the limits so they appear correctly I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In the proof of $C_0$ being closed there seems to be a huge gap. Where exactly do you prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(t) = 0$?

Comment: Do you mean the line where I write $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f_n(x) = 0$? $f_n$ is a sequence of functions in $C_0$ so it follows from the definition of $C_0$ that  $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f_n(x) = 0$.

Comment: Indeed, I meant $\displaystyle \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} f(t) = 0$. Sorry. But you still have to prove that.